# Randomly include JSPs

Tags: java, jsp

I have many jsp files `row1.jsp, row2.jsp, row3.jsp, ..., row10.jsp` which I would like to include in my main jsp page.

The trick here is I would like to randomize how they are presented, so sometimes they are included this way:

```
<%@include file="/index-rows/row1.jspf"%>
<%@include file="/index-rows/row2.jspf"%>
<%@include file="/index-rows/row3.jspf"%>
```

And other times:

```
<%@include file="/index-rows/row2.jspf"%>
<%@include file="/index-rows/row1.jspf"%>
<%@include file="/index-rows/row3.jspf"%>
```

I tried the following but I realised I cannot add a `<%=  %>` within a `<%@include>` tag.

```
<%
HashMap<String, String> foo = ...some code...
String[] pages = { "row1.jspf", "row2.jspf", "row3.jspf" };
for (String p : pages) {
     %><%@include file="/index-rows/<%= p %>"%><%
}
%>
```

Condition: The included files uses the variable `foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%@ include %>` is a static include directive. This means that it's evaluated at compilation time, and thus can't use dynamic file names.

Use a [dynamic include](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro10.html) to do what you want: `<jsp:include page="..."/>`. You'll need to store `foo` in a request attribute for the included page to use it, though.

And please, learn how to use the JSP EL. Scriptlets should not be used anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advise I'll go pick up JSP EL.